# How to auto call function in visualForce page without using JavaScript?

Tags: salesforce, cloud, visualforce, apex

I am trying to make a component in visualForce who apply some treatement on any List that I pass by parameter :

```
<apex:component controller="TheController">

<!-- Attribute -->
<apex:attribute name="list_Of_Objects"
    description="Received varaible of data type string"
    assignTo="{!listAllObjects}" type="MyObjects[]"
    required="true" />

    {Code of the component}
</apex:component>
```

This is how I call my Component :

```
<apex:page Controller="ComponentController">

    <c:TheComponent list_Of_Objects="{!objects}" />

</apex:page>
```

My component should display the information on the list, but the parameter passed to my parameter are initialized after that the constructor of ComponentController was called, so I cant call any other method to do the treatement on the arrays (passed in parameter)

One solution consist to make a button on the visualForce page that call the specific method when its clicked, but its not what I want.

I wish to know if there is any way to 'auto-call' a method in ComponentController class, without using JavaScript (just VisualForce or apex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The (simplified) [order of execution](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_lifecycle.htm) for component controllers is:

- constructor
- component's parameters (assignTo's)
- getters as required by visualforce

In constructor all params are blank, not passed yet. You have access to whatever was in the URL of main page (`ApexPages.currentPage()`) and that's about it.

So the trick is to have your "decorators" run not in constructor but in a helper getter method

```
public class ComponentController{

    public List<MyOBjects> listAllObjects {get; set;}

    public ComponentController(){}

    public List<SomethingDecorated> getBetterObjects(){
        List<SomethingDecorated> betterObjects = doYourMagic(listAllObjects);
        return betterObjects;
    }
}
```

And then in component simply reference `{!betterObjects}`.

Comment: thank you for your answer .. but I wish to know how can I call 'getBetterObjects' method ? (using URL ??)

Comment: The way I've written it'll be called when Visualforce encounters `{!betterObjects}` on the page. It'll start by looking for such variable and if none found - will call your method. So you'll have it as soon as page loads but after the parameters were passed to component. If you really want to call stuff from javascript - read the documentation for `<apex:actionFunction>` (best for submitting the page's form like a button click) and "remote actions" (best for really fetching data to JS without reloading the page): https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_js_remoting.htm